# UnicodeDecodeError on Localhost with Django and Optimizely

Tags: django, unicode, optimizely

I'm trying to test my experiments locally before pushing to the live version of the site, so my experiment is targeted to:
localhost:8000/ (simple match)
The experiment preview however doesn't load.  If I point to the live version of the site it works fine.

Its a django app, viewing the source when I go localhost:8000 in the browser I can see that the optimizely snippet is present.

This is my stacktrace from django

```
self.finish_request(request, client_address)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
File "/Users/james/pubfront/riidr_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 126, in __init__
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 59660)
super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 655, in __init__
self.handle()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 599, in process_request_thread
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 124, in handle
self.finish_request(request, client_address)
if not self.parse_request(): # An error code has been sent, just exit
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 286, in parse_request
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
self.send_error(400, "Bad request syntax (%r)" % requestline)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 368, in send_error
self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
File "/Users/james/pubfront/riidr_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 126, in __init__
self.send_response(code, message)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 385, in send_response
super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
self.log_request(code)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 655, in __init__
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 422, in log_request
self.handle()
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 124, in handle
self.requestline, str(code), str(size))
File "/Users/james/pubfront/riidr_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 138, in log_message
msg = "[%s] %s\n" % (self.log_date_time_string(), format % args)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I doubt its a problem with the code as it works fine with the live version, I think I must be missing something to do with pointing optimizely at localhost.

I think its probably some security problem or middleware problem, but I haven't had any luck identifying it.

The middleware on the site are:

```
   89:     "tools.middleware.ContentLengthWriter",
   90:     "stats.middleware.LastActivityMiddleware",
   91:     "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
   92:     "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
   93:     "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
   94:     "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
   95:     "mobile.middleware.MobileMiddleware",
   96:     "tools.recently_viewed.RecentlyViewedMiddleware",
   97:     "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
   98:     "pagination.middleware.PaginationMiddleware",
   99:     "django.middleware.transaction.TransactionMiddleware",
  100:     "tools.middleware.UserBasedExceptionMiddleware",
  101:     "tools.middleware.ExceptionMiddleware",
  102:     "django.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware",
  103:     "tools.middleware.ReadOnlyMiddleware",
```

Answer (score 0):

The problea is already fix in newer version of Django (https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23398)

The bug was related about using HTTPS with localhost.